# Interface InputFormat vs Class InputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am a newbie to Hadoop, I am trying to learn it and came across 2 versions of `InputFormat`.

[org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html)

[org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html)

The explanation of both apis seems to be same but one is interface and other is a class. Can someone please help me why there are 2 APIs with same explanation in Hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce has undergone a complete overhaul in hadoop-0.23 and it is called as MapReduce 2.0 (MRv2) or YARN.

org/apache/hadoop/**mapred**/InputFormat refers to hadoop MRV1

org/apache/hadoop/**mapreduce**/InputFormat refers to hadoop MRV2

Both these libraries refer to same functionality.

MRV2 is a rewrite of MRV1 for the compatibility of YARN architecture.

Comment: In addition to it, for easily finding the class/interface of MR1 or MR2, just check the package fully qualified name. `mapred` is MR1 and `mapreduce` is MR2 package series.